# Why doesn't Ruby logger support log device switch after initialization?

Tags: ruby, logging

Why doesn't Ruby logger from the standard library support dynamic log device switch? Isn't there any public API for that? I can switch the log level, but not the log device. For example:

```
logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
logger.logdev = LogDevice.new('/tmp/any.log')
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `logdev=' for #<Logger>
```

I suppose that it relates to some thread safe setup, probably mutex over log device or some underground file locking. So I'd like to understand the details and the initial intentions.

In [serverengine](https://github.com/treasure-data/serverengine) gem, `ServerEngine::DaemonLogger` subclasses `Logger`, and adds the required behaviour with [`#logdev=`](https://github.com/treasure-data/serverengine/blob/master/lib/serverengine/daemon_logger.rb#L43) method.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but when I want to switch the device, I do a `logger.close` and then create a new Logger object. Of course this slightly different from what you want to achieve. My guess is that simply switching devices was not provided in the original implementation.

Comment: This is not a programming question. If you want to know _how_ to do that then [there is an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971803/dynamically-change-the-logdevice-of-ruby-logger), and you could probably rig something yourself by using [the `reopen` method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger/LogDevice.html#method-i-reopen) of the `Logger::LogDevice` class.

Comment: @user1934428, after some little research, my sentiments the same – Ruby core team thinks it's not needed for the community.
https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11955#note-7

Comment: @Tensho : I think also that the semantics of switching the logdevice is not really easy to define in a generally usable way. For instance, if I start with a rotating logger, then switch the logdevice to STDOUT, and then switch back to a rotating logger (maybe of the same name?), should it continue where it was left? How is the number of generations to be defined? This just asks for trouble, and it's much cheaper to simply throw away the old Logger object and create a new one.